# Web App picks up logged in user name when running localhost but not when deployed

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I have an Webforms app, I am adapting it to use Azure AD to pick up a user name.   I used the following to guide me:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/

It all works just fine running on localhost.   When I deploy it to xxxx.azurewebsites.net, the site comes up, but none of the AAD information is available.  I'm not sure where to begin to diagnose this.

I have changed the web.config file clientID and TenantID values and the redirect URI as described in the link above.

Just trying to use:  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name returns blank when on azurewebsites.net, but returns my email address that I used to authenticate with Microsoft.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Could you please tell me what is "name" you need? Could you please provide some screenshots you can see?

Comment: When running localhost, it redirect to the MS login, page and upon return HttpContext.CurrentUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true, and HttpContext.CurrentUser.Identity.Name = my email addr.   When I run deployed to azure, I get false and an empty string.   I did add the azure deployment website as a 2nd redirecturi....and changed the references to https://localhost:44385 to the azure website in the startup code file... I'm sure I have made a mistake, but not sure where to start here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have configured it correctly. Could you please try something like below for getting the claims value:

```
var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

        //You get the user’s first and last name below:
        ViewBag.Name = userClaims?.FindFirst("name")?.Value;

        // The 'preferred_username' claim can be used for showing the username
        ViewBag.Username = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;

        // The subject/ NameIdentifier claim can be used to uniquely identify the user across the web
        ViewBag.Subject = userClaims?.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

        // TenantId is the unique Tenant Id - which represents an organization in Azure AD
        ViewBag.TenantId = userClaims?.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;
```

Also ,please check the below link for further reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link.   I downloaded this sample, followed the steps, and the sample app seems to work fine.   Part of my complication is that my app is NOT mvc based, and I not particularly current on the web technologies.   I did port the Startup / Owin code, and that code does run.   However, something is missing, as my target app does not direct to Microsoft for authentication, it simply returns that the user is not authorized.    So what extra do I need to get this stuff rolling for me non-MVC app.   Glad to post whatever is need to help resolve this